# copy and change data type of multiple files with different schema in data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I need to copy multiple files with different structure in azure data factory from a ADLS gen2 to another and transforming the data types of each file.

Is there any way that I can do it generically or I really need to deal with each file separetly.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by different structure ? Can you share more information on input and expected output ?